# Shortest code to make INITEX produce printable output

Tags: tex-core

What is the shortest sequence of characters that will lead to a printable page of output when processed by `INITEX`? Meaning no formats like `plain.tex` preloaded, and with output of positive width and height. The best I could do so far are the following 19 characters:

```
\font\@=cmr9\@A\end
```

Is there any typesettable material that does not require a font to be loaded and that can occur on its own at the top of the page?

Comment: Welcome to this site! Interesting (even if strange) question :)

Comment: thank you :) well eventually I learnt from it that glue and kerns are removed if there is nothing to be printed, and that this doesn't apply to rules

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is 19 characters and no fonts

```
\hrule width9in\end
```

Or if you are allowed to scroll past errors save 2 characters so (17)

```
\hrule width9\end
```

where if you scroll past the missing units error you get a 9pt rule.

This is same output as yours, but one less character input (18)

```
\font\@cmr9\@A\end
```

and changing the font gets down to 17 characters

```
\font\@pxr\@A\end
```

There are several three letter fonts in texlive, but no two or one letter ones but if renaming (any) font is allowed so that `z.tfm` is available then the count comes down to 15

```
\font\@z\@A\end
```

Or 14 with a font with name of length 0 (tex is happy, your dvi driver might be less so)

```
cp /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/cm/cmr10.tfm .tfm
cp /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/pk/ljfour/public/cm/dpi600/cmr10.pk .pk
```

Then you can use (14)

```
\font\@\@A\end
```

---

In comments the OP asks about

```
\hrule1\end
```

which is shorter but doesn't produce visible output but two blank pages.

the generated box structure is:

```
Completed box being shipped out [0]
\vbox(0.0+0.0)x0.0
.\glue(\topskip) 0.0
.\rule(0.4+0.0)x*


Completed box being shipped out [0]
\vbox(0.0+0.0)x0.0
.\glue(\topskip) 0.0
.\hbox(0.0+0.0)x0.0
..\hbox(0.0+0.0)x0.0
..\penalty 10000
..\glue(\parfillskip) 0.0
..\glue(\rightskip) 0.0
.\hbox(0.0+0.0)x0.0
.\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fill

 )
```

`\vsize` is 0pt so more or less any feasible break point will be taken, here on the first page you get the hrule which has non zero height but zero width as `hsize` is  zero, then the second page has the paragraph generated by the text `1` except that it is set in nullfont so nothing gets typeset.

Comment: I have no idea of the `INITEX` nor the TeX core. Could you explain the sentence `\hrule width9in\end`? Thanks!

Comment: @manooooh it makes a line .4pt high and 9in wide

Comment: @manooooh `\hrule` is a TeX primitive that makes a **h**orizontal **rule**, something like a visible black bar. You can give it a width, so you can read `\hrule width 9in` as "a horizontal rule of width nine inches". After that, `\end` is a (separate and independent) TeX primitive for ending the TeX job; without it TeX would be waiting for further instructions. As for the other option: `\font\@cmr9` defines a font named `\@` to be read from `cmr9.tfm` (any "other" char will do: `\font \; cmr9` or `\:` etc). After that, `\@` selects that font, then `A` puts down the character `A` from the font.

Comment: to be fair, if file system manipulation is allowed we can just `\input0` some file named `0` that does everything for us, but I see how much the question depends on the distribution then. the best solution working with just the `initex` program seems to be the 17 char `\hrule` one since that seems to be the only font-independent typesettable material and there doesn't seem to be any shorter rule specification.

Comment: @wave I did mark the more dubious ones:-) but I think that's different if you input the file you are executing tex code of some length, but in your example you already assumed that a file called cmr9.tfm exited in the path,  the fact that texlive happens to have a pxr.tfm but not a .tfm in the path  is more a time dependent property of the texlive distribution rather than of initex, and I thought it interesting that `.tfm` does in fact work (not something I'd tried before in 30+ years using tex:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle sure, as I admitted my question is not very well defined :) though we could also argue that the fact texlive does not come with a `0` file with some code in it is a time-dependent property of the distribution ... but yes, interesting to see the font name can be empty :D

Comment: @DavidCarlisle do you have any idea why `\hrule1\end` compiles for me with `initex` and gives two empty pages of output?

Comment: @wave I added a note about that to my answer

Comment: @DavidCarlisle interesting, thank you. I suppose my dvi viewer just refuses to open one empty page (like `1\end`), but is happy to display two empty pages.

Comment: @wave `dviasm` is the dvi viewer of choice here:-)